# How can I install new liferay-ui:message keys for my portlet to use in Liferay 6.0.6?

Tags: internationalization, liferay, liferay-6

I have the ff. in my JSP:

```
<liferay-ui:message key="my-own-message-key" />
```

But when the JSP is rendered, I see "my-own-message-key" where I expect "My own message key."  I have already tried the method described [here](http://kamalkantrajput.blogspot.com/2011/03/i18n-liferay-6x.html) and in the Overriding a *Language.properties* File section of the Liferay Developer's Guide.

Comment: What version of Liferay are you using? Are you creating a JSP in your own portlet or are you overriding an existing JSP from Liferay core?

Comment: 6.0.6.  I am creating a JSP in my own portlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed Overriding a *Language.properties* File section of the Liferay Developer's Guide.  But this time, manually copied my Language-ext_xx_YY.properties into the portlet's classpath (e.g., docroot/WEB-INF/classes/content/Language-ext_xx_YY.properties) so it can be found by Liferay during runtime.  Maybe it didn't work the first time because the Liferay IDE didn't copy it over automatically on build.

Comment: No, I use the Liferay IDE plugin to Eclipse.

Comment: New entry did not reflect in WAR build deployed in test server.  No idea why.  Works in local server.